# C# project lost, anyways to recover it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After a hard drive disaster, my main partition had been formatted. As a result, my C# project ( a small management software) was lost. However, I have copied its DEBUG folder in to my USB ( for testing it in another computer). So, is there anyways for me to recover the lost project or I have to start again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not easy. You can use [`Reflector`](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to recover the source, but resources and the like are harder. I have a [step-by-step on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/11/reverse-compiling-windows-forms.html) that works for some (most?) Windows Forms projects.

P.S. Use source control. There's free SVN hosts (and probably Mercurial/Git, too), even for commercial projects...

Comment: Note that the source will likely not be entirely as originally typed. The conversion from source to IL to source is not perfect.

Comment: In particular, no comments will be recovered. :(

Comment: One doesn't realize the importance of comments until they're gone, I guess.